# TSQL invalid HAVING count

Tags: t-sql, having

I am using SSMS 2008 and trying to use a HAVING statement.  This should be a real simple query.  However, I am only getting one record returned event though there are numerous duplicates.

Am I doing something wrong with the HAVING statement here?  Or is there some other function that I could use instead?

```
select
      address_desc,
      people_id
from 
      dbo.address_view
where people_id is not NULL
group by people_id , address_desc
having count(*) > 1
```

sample data from address_view:

```
people_id                            address_desc
----------                           ------------
Murfreesboro, TN  37130          F15D1135-9947-4F66-B778-00E43EC44B9E
11 Mohawk Rd., Burlington, MA 01803 C561918F-C2E9-4507-BD7C-00FB688D2D6E
Unknown, UN  00000                    C561918F-C2E9-4507-BD7C-00FB688D2D6E
Jacksonville, NC  28546          FC7C78CD-8AEA-4C8E-B93D-010BF8E4176D
Memphis, TN  38133                    8ED8C601-5D35-4EB7-9217-012905D6E9F1
44 Maverick St., Fitchburg, MA  8ED8C601-5D35-4EB7-9217-012905D6E9F1
```

Comment: You don't seem to have any duplicates in the data you provided.

Comment: The having statement is correct, but your grouping might not be, have you tried `group by people_id` without `, address_desc`?

Comment: Yes, there are duplicates. See the address_desc column.

Comment: @salvationishere: But that's not a duplicate; the `people_id` is different. The `group by` is going to group all of the unique *combinations* of `people_id` and `address_desc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GROUP BY is going to lump your duplicates together into a single row.

I think instead, you want to find all `people_id` values with duplicate `address_desc`:

```
SELECT a.address_desc, a.people_id
    FROM dbo.address_view a
        INNER JOIN (SELECT address_desc
                        FROM dbo.address_view
                        GROUP BY address_desc
                        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t
            ON a.address_desc = t.address_desc
```

Comment: Thanks Joe!  This was almost exactly what I needed!  I actually needed addresses for duplicate people records instead.  So I just replaced your logic above by substituting people_id for address_desc and it worked like a charm!

Comment: @salvationishere Makes sense. I think you must have had the labels reversed on your sample data in the question.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

using row_number and partition you can find the duplicate occurrences where row_num>1

```
select address_desc,
people_id,
row_num
from
(
select
  address_desc,
  people_id,
  row_number() over (partition by address_desc order by address_desc) row_num
from 
  dbo.address_view
where people_id is not NULL
```

) x
where row_num>1